# loop csv content in a jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

i am trying to build an output based on a jinj2 template using a csv as input. I've search through and couldnt find much information to build a solution.

So far i have the following code:

```
import sys, os
import jinja2
import csv

in_file="csv_file.csv"
jinja_template = "test.j2"
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="."))

with open(in_file, "rb") as FD:
    reader = csv.DictReader(FD)
    for vals in reader:
        gen_template = env.get_template(jinja_template)
        output = gen_template.render(vals)
        print output
```

My csv file looks like this:

```
country,city
UK,London
UK,Manchester
UK,Liverpool
US,Chicago
US,Denver
US,Atlanta
```

And my jinja2 template looks like this:

```
country: {{country}} has cities {{city}}
```

Following is the output i am trying to achieve:

```
country: UK has cities: London, Manchester, Liverpool
country: US has cities: Chicago, Denver, Atlanta
```

I believe i need to run for loop within the j2 template in order to build the city names next to the country.

When i run the code above i actually get the individual country <> city names as seperately like this:

```
country: UK has cities London
country: UK has cities Manchester
country: UK has cities Liverpool
country: US has cities Chicago
country: US has cities Denver
country: US has cities Atlanta
```

Appreciate if someone can provide some pointers on how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your input csv is sorted by country, [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?#itertools.groupby) can help:

```
from io import StringIO
from jinja2 import Template
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from csv import DictReader


csv_data = '''country,city
UK,London
UK,Manchester
UK,Liverpool
US,Chicago
US,Denver
US,Atlanta
'''

tmpl = 'country: {{country}} has cities {{cities}}'
template = Template(tmpl)

with StringIO(csv_data) as file:
    rows = DictReader(file)
    for country, groups in groupby(rows, key=itemgetter('country')):
        cities = ', '.join(row['city'] for row in groups)
        output = template.render(country=country, cities=cities)
        print(output)
```

which prints

```
country: UK has cities London, Manchester, Liverpool
country: US has cities Chicago, Denver, Atlanta
```

---

if you prefer to do the `join` inside jinja, this is an option:

```
tmpl = 'country: {{country}} has cities {{cities | join(", ")}}'
template = Template(tmpl)

with StringIO(csv_data) as file:
    rows = DictReader(file)
    for country, groups in groupby(rows, key=itemgetter('country')):
        cities = (row['city'] for row in groups)
        output = template.render(country=country, cities=cities)
```

---

if you need to be able to append a header, you need to collect all the data from your file first (done here using an OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

tmpl = '''Countries and cities:
{%-for country, cities in grouped.items()%}
country: {{coutry}} has cities {{cities | join(", ")}}
{%-endfor%}'''
template = Template(tmpl)

with StringIO(csv_data) as file:
    rows = DictReader(file)
    grouped = OrderedDict()
    for country, groups in groupby(rows, key=itemgetter('country')):
        grouped[country] = [item['city'] for item in groups]
    output = template.render(grouped=grouped)
    print(output)
```

which then yields:

```
Countries and cities:
country:  has cities London, Manchester, Liverpool
country:  has cities Chicago, Denver, Atlanta
```

Comment: looks great, i am gonna read more about itertools.
One question though, if i add another piece of text say even a heading to the template file it actually will print as many times as we have contents in csv file. How can i prevent that

Comment: this is how it looks like if i add a heading in the template file:


`This is the heading of the file:`

`country: UK has cities: London, Manchester, Liverpool`

`This is the heading of the file:`

`country: US has cities: Chicago, Denver, Atlanta`

Comment: this is very nice. thank you.
I have one question, i am interested about the itertool and its grouping features.

for example will the grouping also works with multiple columns,

so for example if i had a csv file that has data like this:

`country_a, city_a,country_b,city_b`

Would i be able to group say country_a in one iteration and country_b in one iteration?

Comment: that depends on what you want in the end... you are pretty free what you use as `key` in `groupby`. any function can be used. without the actual data and an example of what you want it's hard to tell...

Comment: in a case like this i believe i can have a seperate for loop for the second grouping?

i have say this csv (sample)
`country_a,city_a,country_b,city_b`
`uk_a,london_a,uk_b,london_b`
`uk_a,manchester_a,uk_b,manchester_b`
`us_a,ny_a,us_b,ny_b`
`us_a,la_a,us_b,la_b`

i tried to group all cities depending on either country_a or country_b
so my output would look like this:

`uk_a cities london_a, manchester_a`
`uk_b cities london_b, manchester_b`

Comment: in that case i would not use `groupby` at all but create an (ordered) dictionary for the countries; such that `dct['uk_a'] = ['london_a', 'manchester_a']` etc.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your example! How can I add a third information to the template e.g. Postcode? I've tried to add postcode but it won't shown.

Comment: @Goeks that depends on your input and your desired output... maybe try something and if it does not exactly do what you want, post it as a new question.